# Extending Generic.__class_getitem__ in Python to accept more params

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, metaclass

How can one extend `__class_getitem__` for a Python `Generic` class?  I want to add arguments to `__class_getitem__` while having some be propagated upwards to `Generic.__class_getitem__`.

Please see the below code snippet for an example use case (that doesn't run):

```py
from typing import ClassVar, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    cls_attr: ClassVar[int]

    def __class_getitem__(cls, cls_attr: int, item):
        cls.cls_attr = cls_attr
        return super().__class_getitem__(item)

    def __init__(self, arg: T):
        pass

foo = Foo[1, bool](arg=True)
```

Gives me this `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 17, in <module>
    foo = Foo[1, bool](arg=True)
TypeError: Foo.__class_getitem__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

Comment: Your implementation of `__class_getitem__` does not have the required signature [`(cls, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__).

Comment: `Foo[1, bool]` isn't passing two arguments to `__class_getitem__`, it is passing *a single argument*, a *tuple*, `1, bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga suggests, this is the way to go:

```py
from typing import ClassVar, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    cls_attr: ClassVar[int]

    def __class_getitem__(cls, item: tuple[int, T]):
        cls.cls_attr = item[0]
        return super().__class_getitem__(item[1])

    def __init__(self, arg: T):
        self.arg = arg


foo = Foo[1, bool](arg=True)
assert foo.cls_attr == 1
assert foo.arg
```

Unfortunately, it looks like Python type inspection tooling is not advanced enough to understand this pattern.  For example, `mypy==0.971` (Sept 2022) doesn't support `__class_getitem__` yet per https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11501.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have two generic vars then you can do that like this:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
V = TypeVar("V")

class Foo(Generic[T, V]):
    
    def __init__(self, arg: T):
        pass

foo: Foo[int, bool] = Foo(arg=True)
```

Comment: That was not what I was looking for, though thank you for sharing nonetheless!